# Dotnet core routes from different Controller return 404

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core

I have problem with dotnet core 1.0. I need to use route from Controller in different project (and different namespace). How is possible to do it?

**This is my startup in running project:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //this line I've tried to add (CmsController is from different project, linked to startup project)
            services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(CmsController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            services.AddCms<ApplicationDbContext>(Configuration, true);

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }
```

**Here is simple CmsController:**

```
 public class CmsController : Controller
    {
        public ICmsService CmsService { get; protected set; }

        public CmsController(ICmsService cmsService)
        {
            this.CmsService = cmsService;
        }

        [Route("")]          
        private async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return await this.ReturnResult();
        }
      ...
}
```

**In my routes extension I have something like this:**

```
public static Action<IRouteBuilder> Register()
        {
            return routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "cmsRoute",
                    "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    "cmsFrontend",
                    "/{controller=Cms}/{action=Index}",
                    new {controller = "CmsController", action = "Index", Area = string.Empty});
            };
        }
```

**And register in startup method in main project:**

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {                       
        CmsRouteExtensions.Register();

        SeedRouteExtensions.Register();

    });
```

When I try to run HomeController in main project, everything works fine. But when I run it without HomeController (comment Index action and comment routes for this) in main, I've got 404. But I should see routing from CmsController in root domain (homepage) http://localhost/

Where is the problem please?

Thank you!

Comment: Solved. Hm, solutions is correct, but action has to be PUBLIC :-D This is copying problem.. Thank you for your time.